# Get all inputs with class on page not in div

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a couple of `class="email"` inputs on my page. I need to fetch all of those, except the ones that are in a div with `id="addCustomer"`.

What I've tried so far:

```
$.each($(".email").not("#addCustomer"), function () {
    // Code...
});
```

---

```
$.each($("body").find(".email").not("#addCustomer"), function () {
    // Code...
});
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure whether I'm using the `.not()` method properly.

Comment: `$('div').not('#addCustomer').find('.email')` try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter it:

```
$(".email").not("#addCustomer .email").each(function(){/*Code...*/});
```

***As a side note:*** depending what you do with `/*Code...*/`, you maybe doesn't need any `each` loop. Most jQuery setter methods work on collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$(".email").not("#addCustomer .email").each(function () {
    // Code...
});
```

Comment: Oops sorry, now we have both same answer following my edit (and yours) :(  Get my vote! :)

Comment: hihi. I've just noticed that. Previously you were using filter right?